# Is posible to overrride Windows Installer Error Messages from WIX

Tags: user-interface, wix, windows-installer

In the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372835(v=vs.85).aspx) of windows installer are the messages that windows installer will show when errors appear.

It is possible to overwrite those messages in a WIX project?

Try to use

```
<UI>
    <Error Id="1920">My overridden message</Error>        
</UI>
```

proposed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759039/wix-internall-strings-cannot-be-localize)

but I got the following error:

```
error LGHT0091: Duplicate symbol 'Error:1920' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.
```

Comment: Those are the messages that have to be entered in the Errors table by default in an msi package. You can add your own or modify them. Modifying them though would probably be a *bad* idea - the message would be ungooglable, resulting in a support call each time anything went wrong. Imagine trying to troubleshoot that support call when the error message reported by the client is unrecognizable

Comment: I understand the risk of modifying them, but How can be modified? so far I have not found how to do it.

Comment: Are you looking to *localize* the error messages perhaps? Then you should add *localized* versions for specific languages, not replace the existing ones. These errors are already localized in a lot of languages.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759039/wix-internall-strings-cannot-be-localize) - shows how to add localized strings for specific IDs

Comment: I do not want to localize the error messages. I want to modify one specific message.

Comment: Trying the use of error element, could be possible.

Comment: it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the source code of WIX and modify all the UI as you want, including the flow of the dialogs and the Error messages strings.

You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723840/customizing-text-in-the-standard-wix-dialogs).