# Problems customizing WIX InvalidDirDlg

Tags: wix, windows-installer

In product.wxs I have:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```

In LocalizableResources.wxl I have tried to override some strings:

```
<String Id="BrowseDlg_Title">I was here</String>
<String Id="InvalidDirDlg_Title">I was here</String>
<String Id="InvalidDirDlgText">I was here</String>
```

It works for the BrowseDlg, but not for the InvalidDirDlg. When I run the installer and I try to choose a DVD drive for the install directory, the error message I get is "The volume D:\ is currently unavailable. Please select another." This isn't even the expected string from WixUI_en-us.wxl, which is "Installation directory must be on a local hard drive."

How can I override the InvalidDirDlg? Why is it displaying the wrong error message?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code in the question *does* work! If I choose a USB stick I get the InvalidDirDlg popping up with the overridden strings. It's only the DVD drive that doesn't work.

I was able to override the error for the DVD drive by using an Error element as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18764513/1883060).